# JPA Stored procedure NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, jpa-2.1

I'm following this [JPA 2.1 StoredProcedureQuery](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics) as an example for what I'm working on.

Anyway, I have a Stored Procedure in the database named "**XYZ"** and I created a class:

```
@NameStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "createXYZ",
        procedureName = "ZYX",
        resultClasses = XYZObj.class,
        parameters={
             @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
             @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.OUT, name = "id", type = String.class)})
public class XYZObj {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Here is my DAO class:

```
@Stateless
public class XYZDAO{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    public String createXYZ(String name){
         StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("createXYZ");
         query.setParameter("name", name);
         query.execute();
         return query.getOutputParameterValue("id")
    }
   ...
}
```

RESTFUL:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/XYZ")
public class XYZServlet{
   @EJB
   private XYZDAO xyzDao;
   @GET
   @Path("test")
   public Response test(){
         xyzDao.createXYZ("myname");
         return Response.satus(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
   }
}
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

...

I'm getting NoSuchMethodError at this line.

```
 StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("createXYZ");
```

Does anyone knows why? Am I using the right version of JPA? Did I miss something?

Here is the actual error that i'm getting.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to java.lang.exception
     at javax.ejb.EJBException.getCauseByException(EJBException.java:23)
     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:63)
     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:54)
     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:67)
     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBExceptionMapper.toResponse(EJBExceptionMapper.java:54)
    truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Thanks

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be case to java.lang.exception` ... **case** ? is that a copy paste of the error? In any case I would bet all my chips that you're using incompatible versions of some libraries. Check that you're not importing JPA < 2.1 by mistake.

Comment: sorry i misspelled that. Fixed
I'm sure that i'm using JPA 2.1 from project Facets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project compilation looks like it's correctly referencing JPA 2.1, but a `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that the `EntityManager` available at runtime is from an earlier JPA version.  The `EntityManager` is probably provided by your EJB container.  Consult the documentation of whatever application server you are using to determine how to upgrade to JPA 2.1.

EDIT:
You should also mark whatever maven dependencies that are provided by your application server as `<scope>provided</scope>` in your pom.xml.

Comment: I know it's been a while but I just talked to a guy at my company about this problem and he said that eclipselink already includes JPA 2.1 so it should be good.